# How can I help with moderation if I haven't got enough reputation?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, moderation, site-specific

I like doing the moderation like editing posts, reviewing, removing, etc.—simply cleaning Stack Overflow. But I don't like so much writing answers or good questions.

If I'm good at moderation, but not so good at writing/answering questions, I will never achieve enough reputation to have access to moderator tools (or that will take very long).

So, what should I do to help with moderation, but without having to earn so much reputation (e.g., access to 10k moderation tools)? Is there a way to get permissions or moderator access earlier? Who should I contact? What should I do?

Comment: The only way would be to be an elected moderator (and even then you would still need some rep to be eligable).  However it might be difficult to build up that level of trust without involment in the main activities of the site. On stack overflow we are midway through an election at the moment so it may be a while before there is a new round

Comment: The question is: How someone will start to believe that you are a good moderator if you just don't participate in the community? It's your word versus the community itself. It's the most democratic way to give moderation powers to someone without a personal contact to prove the reputation.

Comment: You've got to walk before you can run

Comment: @JoaoPauloRabelo I will participate in community, but I other way. Not by writing questions/answers, by moderating

Comment: @Ty221 If you do not understand the subject matter well enough to contribute good questions and answers then how can you claim to know the subject matter well enough to moderate it? How can you prove to the community that you have this expertise? If you can come up with a good method that proves to the community that you are as expert as 10k rep users without answering questions, then propose that as a possible path to earning the required reputation. If you can't prove this expertise to the community, then the community isn't wrong to tell you to take it slowly and show them via normal means.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have 2000 rep on SO which means you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

- flag (requires 15 so almost everyone can do this)
- comment if a post needs attention you can't provide (needs 50)
- work in the [review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review) (needs 500)
- edit any post without review and approval (needs 2000 but you can suggest with no rep)

The only things you can't do are cast close votes (but your close flags will get posts into the giant close queue where others may see them) and handle flags. The things you **are** able to do are the workhorse effort of the site: flag stuff, clean up, reword for those who didn't write clearly, vote up good stuff, vote down bad stuff. There's no real need for you to do different kinds of things if you're happy to do those. Thanks for helping to make the site better.

Comment: That's already 2/3 the way to casting close and open votes, too.

Answer (score 4):

This is by design.  If you haven't contributed enough exemplary content to the community for the community to trust you to take control of other user's content, then you won't be provided access to do so.

It might take a long time, but if you are truly interested in doing more than you are currently capable, practice by providing content to the site that others will appreciate.